# Ursina - how to add fog correctly

Tags: python, ursina

I'm (once again!) asking about a problem with Ursina...

I know that Ursina has a scene.fog, and I'm kind of assuming it's for 3D games. I want to add fog to my game, but setting scene.fog_density and scene.fog_color does nothing.

Am I doing something wrong? How do I add fog to my game?

I'm using the (mostly) default FirstPersonController

My code:

```
app = Ursina(development_mode=False, show_ursina_splash_screen=True,fullscreen=True,title="Maze FPS")

random.seed(0)
### SHADERS ###
Entity.default_shader = lit_with_shadows_shader

scene.fog_density = .1
scene.fog_color = color.red
```

I've tried various fog densities (.1, 1, and 3) and colors (color.black, color.red, color.green). afaik it didn't have any effect

Comment: Please show what you did. Otherwise it's very hard to say if you did something wrong.

Comment: @pokepetter, ah, you're right. Don't know why that didn't occur to me. Sorry! I've added the relevent code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lit_with_shadows_shader doesn't support fog at the moment. The default shader does however. The way you set fog color and fog density is correct.

Comment: So I'd need to switch everything to use the default shader if I wanted to use fog?

Comment: @Psychon Night There is no shader by default.

Comment: @pokepetter can you help me to make realistic water in ursina?